# Is it a problem if a UK visa was issued but not used?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

Last year, my wife and I were issused 6-month visieor visas for the UK. She did not travel with me and, therefore, didn't use her visa. I am currently applying for a visitor visa for my daughter and myself.

Will the fact that my didn't use her visa have any negative affect on our new application?

Answer (score 3):

Generally No. Consular officers know travel plans are not static and plans change all the time. So far as the unused visa was not fraudulently obtained, the new application will be evaluated on its own merits. I have previously had a UK visitor visa I didn't use and procured another later without any complication.

Comment: @SheikPaul SE does not encourage OP to use comments to ask new questions or to chat, so it would be preferable not to encourage that. Comments get deleted, Q & A's don't and add value to SE.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53628/discussion-on-answer-by-sheik-paul-is-it-a-problem-if-a-uk-visa-was-issued-but-n).

Comment: @Dorothy Noted. I thought it was going to be a minor followup to his original question.